# X is totally ordered under ≤ if and only if X follows the law of trichotomy?

Tags: order-theory

I'm having trouble with this proof. I know that this proof requires two parts.

My attempt so far:

Proof: ($\Rightarrow$)

Assume $X$ is a totally ordered set under $\le$.

Let $m,n$ be two arbitrary element of $X$.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I fixed it.

Comment: What is $X$? Are there any other assumptions on $\leq$? The law of trichotomy I am familiar with says that every real number is negative, zero, or positive.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @CarlMummert: The "law of trichotomy" can also refer to the property of any two elements satisfying $a \lt b$, $a = b$, or $a \gt b$.  So in effect this "law of trichotomy" is just a restatement of total ordering.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Since $X$ is totally ordered by $\le$, you know that at least one of $m\le n$ and $n\le m$ holds.

- Show that if both hold, then $m=n$.
- Show that if $m\le n$ and $n\not\le m$, then $m<n$.
- Show that if $n\le m$ and $m\not\le n$, then ... ?

Since exactly one of these three cases must occur, this establishes that the relation $m<n$ defined by

> $m<n$ if and only if $m\le n$ and $m\ne n$

satisfies the trichotomy condition.

For the other direction, assume that $<$ satisfies the trichotomy condition, and show that $\le$ totally orders $X$; this is just a matter of checking that $\le$ must have the properties required in order for it to be a total order.

**Added:** Note that I am assuming that $\le$ is known to be a partial order. If that’s not the case, the result is false.

Comment: Take $X = \{a,b,c\}$ and let $a < b$, $b < c$, and $c > a$. This has the property "for all $x,y$, exactly one of $x < y$, $y < x$, or $y = x$ holds", but it is not a total ordering because it is not transitive.

Comment: @Carl: Context (and the low-level nature of the OP’s other questions) suggests that the OP simply failed to mention that $\le$ is assumed to be a partial order. I made that assumption, but inadvertently failed to note it explicitly.